# Azure SQL firewall database bug & contacting technical support

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When you manage ips and enable windows azure services, from my understanding, it's supposed to work with all of the azure services out of the box. This isn't the case currently. You have to actually allow the ip of your cloud app to contact the service.

I tried contacting technical support only to find out you now have to PAY to contact them! What?! SO seems to be the only other place that Azure is talked about.

What's up with this? Am I missing something here? Isn't this just poor customer service?

Comment: Where are you trying to contact the database from?  What error msg are you getting?

Comment: It's a cloud service and a web role contacting it (on Azure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually happens once in a while. Azure dudes add a yet another IP addresses range to be used as cloud services virtual IP addresses, but SQL Azure dudes don't add that range to be treated according to "Windows Azure Services" checkmark enabled. I remember it happened twice to us.

This should have just worked. When the checkmark is set all web roles should be able to connect to SQL Azure. So you're right expecting that this should work.

The workaround is the following. You know the VIP of your cloud service deployment, so you can use "whois" to find where it belongs to. "whois" will say it belongs to Microsoft and provide you with the range of addresses of the whole block. You can then add a firewall rule permitting whole that range.

As to why you have to pay them to report their bug. Microsoft typically has a policy that if you had to pay to get support for something that turns out to be their bug then they reimburse you the expenses. I guess you can use that here too. Anyway the minimal support package costs something like 30 USD per month at this moment so it doesn't look like a major expense. I agree that this is not very convenient, but it is fair to some degree.

One other option to report a problem is using [their forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/category/windowsazureplatform). I have to admit I never had any good experience with that, but I guess that's at least the way to generate some buzz that can help getting more attention to the whole problem.